# Create a numba typed List without looping over a python list

Tags: python, numba

I want to use a `numba.typed.List` (going to call it `List`) to pass into my function which is wrapped in `njit`. However this `List` should be created from an existing python list.

When I look at the [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#typed-list) it seems the way you create a `List` is to initialize it and then append elements to it. However this requires you to loop over an already existing list in python which seems inefficient for large lists.

For example:

```
from numba.typed import List
numba_list = List()
py_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
for e in py_list:
    numba_list.append(e)

In [17]: numba_list[0]
Out[17]: 'a'
```

> Is there a way to set a `List` to the values of a python list without explicitly looping over the python list ?

I am using `numba.__version__` = '0.47.0'

Comment: Everything, even list comprehension, is iterating over the original underneath. Just think: how else would it work? It needs to get every element of the original list anyways, so whether it's some constructor (like build-in python list taking iterables of all kinds) or manual loop, it has to go through all elements.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am working on numba 0.49.1 where you can pass the list by the construction.

```
py_list = [2,3,5]    
number_list = numba.typed.List(py_list)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome! Reasons to keep packages up to date

Comment: Unfortunately it is still quite slow

Comment: True - at least it's concise :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension for typed lists the following way:

```
from numba.typed import List
numba_list = List()
py_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
[numba_list.append(e) for e in py_list]
print(numba_list)
```

Output:

```
ListType[unicode_type]([a, b, c])
```

Figured this from an example at [Numba Deprecation Notice](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-reflection-for-list-and-set-types).

Answer (score 0):

if you are dealing with numeric values, why not use numpy array?

```
import numpy as np
py_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
np_array = np.array(py_list)
```